# iPad and Viewports

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

Im currently developing a WebApp for the iPad, now it depends on the viewport (screen-width and screen-height)

Im currently looking to somehow make it dynamic so when the user rotates the ipad, it actually resizes the viewport of the page

Has anyone done this or attempted it and been successful, i would think its just a small snippet of Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using: "device-width" ?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW19

Answer (score 0):

Just meta viewport and CSS. [Here is a demo](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/demos/ipad-css-layout/) (although it rearranges rather than resizes, the principles are the same).

Comment: not really, as the webapp im developing is sort of a no scroll page, as it's all big buttons and what not, but because im using viewport with "width=screen-width" same for height, it dosent resize on orientation